# 404 error when trying to upgrade Pear

Tags: php, pear

I just followed these instructions to get pear installed on mac os x lion:

However, when I run the upgrade-all, I'm getting 404 errors:

```
$ sudo pear upgrade-all
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php.net appears to be down at the moment. You might try again later. I ran into the same problem trying to install a driver.

Comment: It is down indeed. Might have some luck with mirrors, such as us.pear.php.net. Don't know how to install mirror though.

Comment: Didn't even think to check the obvious! Thanks :-)